# Django Model value is NoneType why?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm making a simple app, calculation app.
The user selects options and based on that options app calculate stuff need to.

The problem is I can't edit numbers before they have been saved in the database.

How can I accomplish that?
Thank you.

I've tried to do a calculation in models.py, but I need 
 when I call a 'def calculate()'  from views.py  it responds with Error (NoneType).

Models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    sirina = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    visina = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    roletne = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    okapnice = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    materijal = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    komore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    krila = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ks = models.IntegerField(default=True)
    kv = models.IntegerField(editable=False, null=True)
    ros = models.IntegerField(editable=False,blank=True, null=True)
    rov = models.IntegerField(editable=False,blank=True, null=True)
    proba = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='2')
    briner = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='2'



    def calculate(self):
        return self.sirina + self.visina
    total = property(calculate)


    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.ks = self.calculate()
        super(Video,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Views.py

```
def showvideo(request):
    form = VideoForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        b = 5000
        sirina = request.POST.get('sirina')
        visina = request.POST.get('visina')
        roletne = request.POST.get('roletne')
        #smejanje = sirina + 5000
        s = sirina
        #k = sirina
        #b = k + 20
        print(s)
        print(sirina)
        if sirina == '100' and roletne =='100':
            print(True)
            a = Video()   ## 
            a.save()      ## From here it respond with error NoneType
                          ## 
        else:
            print(False)

**EDIT**
I have this error:  
"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'/

Traceback : 
File "C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\Desk\django\build\scripts-3.6\final1\calculator\views.py" in showvideo
  26.             a.save()

File "C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\Desk\django\build\scripts-3.6\final1\calculator\models.py" in save
  33.         self.ks = self.total()

File "C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\Desk\django\build\scripts-3.6\final1\calculator\models.py" in calculate
  28.         return self.sirina + self.visina

Exception Type: TypeError at /start/
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

####
Why is self.sirina and self.visina NoneType?
```

Comment: it's not because it's not saved, but when you do `a = Video()`, `sirina` and `visina` are `None` so you cannot add them together. You should assign the values to `a` before calling `save()` and in your `calculate()` method you should check first that  `sirina` and `visina` are not `None` and decide what to do if one of the values is `None`.

Comment: But they don't suppose to be None, because those two fields are Inputs?

Comment: because of `a = Video()`

Comment: How can I make this work?

Comment: Learn python maybe? This is really the lesson 1 about how to instantiate objects from classes in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `a.save()` you should try `form.save()`. you have all your data in a form. There is no point in creating a new instance of `Video` and saving it back again. Also, you should either avoid accepting null values in those fields or handle null conditions in your `calculate` method.

Comment: assuming `VideoForm` is a `ModelForm`.

Comment: Thank you on your replay

Answer (score 0):

You defined `sirina` and `visina` as values that can be `None`:

```
sirina = models.IntegerField(null=True)
visina = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

so whenever you access these attributes, you must be careful about what to do with them. Because when you initialise a `Video` without these values by doing `a = Video()`, they will be `None`.

```
self.visina + self.sirina
```

will raise a `NoneType` error because you can't use `+` on a `None` value.